# How do I set up cron job in Magento for Google product feed?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, cron

I have installed following Magento extension on website.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cpc-strategy-feed-exporter-9392.html

They have given following instruction to set up **cron job**. If cron job will set up perfectly then and only I can create perfect Google product feed with help of this Magento extension.

I have **CPanel of website and able to see Cron Job section** over there. But, I am confused to add command in Command text field.

What exactly Command I require to add over there before click on Add New Cron Job. You can find out attachment to know more about it.

[image]

**Instruction Given By Magento Extension Developer**

You can add a cronjob easily from the Direct control panel. Please follow the steps below in order to setup the cronjob.

1. Login to Direct control panel
2. Click on 'Cron Jobs' option in the home page of Direct Admin control panel.
3. From that page you can setup the time interval at which the cronjob should be executed.

Basically, to apply cronjob to Magento,

add `*/5 * * * *` followed by command `/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsphp5`

```
/home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cron.php
```

in the space provided.

**This will execute the cronjob in every 5 minutes**. To execute cron job in 5th minute of every hour you should add **5 * * * *** followed by above command.

Make sure that you add each information in the box provided correctly.

I have set up cron job on CPanel as follow. But, It's not working. Can you please help me to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a script called `cron.php` that executes all of the cronjobs that extensions create internally in Magento. It's advisable to indeed run this every 5 minutes.

Now in your screenshot the time is set right. All you need to do is add the command in the last box.

```
 /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsphp5 /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cron.php
```

Basically the first part is the path to the PHP executable that will run the script and the second part is the FULL path to the script itself. For me usually using the `php` command is enough to execute a script with PHP but if you're not sure just contact your hosting provider

Comment: I have edited my question. And, I have added screenshot from CPanel where I have set up cron job with this guideline. But, It's not working. Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: is the cronjob itself not working or is there an issue in the cron.php script? If you run the task you've added on the commandline. Does it work then?

Comment: Honestly, I am not getting your point. I am trying to create product feed via Magento extension. And, They are suggesting to add Command during Cron Job creation. But, I am not able to see product feed access path. I am really in hurry to fix this issue. Can you please help me more? If you require more information so please let me know.

Comment: I can see following things on CPanel. My main domain is: xyz.com | username: xyz1 | home directory: /home4/xyz1 Then cron.php is available under /home4/xyz1/public_html/cron.php So, What will command file? Can you please help me?

Comment: Try `php /home4/xyz1/public_html/cron.php`. It's likely the `php` command will work on your server. If not, ask the hosting company what command you should use to execute PHP. They'll likely know.